# nginx vhost not serving static files

Tags: nginx

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.site.dk;
  access_log /var/www/www.site.dk/logs/access.log;
  error_log /var/www/www.site.dk/logs/error.log;

  root /var/www/www.site.dk/;


  location / {

    index index.php index.html;

    if (-f $request_filename) {
      break;
    }

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php last;
      break;
    }
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/www.site.dk$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get nginx to serve any physical file (css, images, js) without doing anything to it put let php handle all other requests. Everything that is not a physical file should be passed to php.

But it's not working, php is being executed, but calling a .css file is also passed to php as a request.

Comment: Better directed at serverfault.com I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.site.dk;
    access_log /var/www/www.site.dk/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/www.site.dk/logs/error.log;

    root /var/www/www.site.dk/;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @fastcgi;
    }

    location ~ .+\.php$ {
        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ { return 400; }
        error_page 418 = @fastcgi;
        return 418;
    }

    location @fastcgi {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        ...
    }
}
```